# Ruby Enumerable#count performance issue in algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I've solved [this problem from LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-subsets/) using Ruby but I'm having some performance issues that I don't understand.

Here's my code:

```
def word_subsets(a, b)
    occurrence_map = max_occurrences(b)
    a.select do |w|
        word_occurrence = letter_occurrence(w)
        occurrence_map.all? { |k, v| v <= word_occurrence[k]  }
    end
end

def letter_occurrence(word)
    Hash.new(0).tap do |occurrences|
        word.each_char { |c| occurrences[c] += 1 }
    end
end

def max_occurrences(b)
    Hash.new(0).tap do |occurrences|
        b.each do |word|
            word_occurrences = letter_occurrence(word)
            word.each_char { |c| occurrences[c] = [occurrences[c], word_occurrences[c]].max }
        end
    end
end
```

This code works but it has not the best runtime and I'm trying to understand why. The most confusing thing I realised reading another Ruby solution is the following: if I make this change in the max_occurrences method:

```
def max_occurrences(b)
    Hash.new(0).tap do |occurrences|
        b.each do |word|
            word.each_char { |c| occurrences[c] = [occurrences[c], word.count(c)].max }
        end
    end
end
```

It results in an importante performance improvement and I really don't understand why. I don't understand why because, the original way I wrote it, does not make a call to the count method for every character. I thought that calling this method would iterate the array, so instead of doing that I compute all the occurences just once. But my approach seems to be worse and I don't know why.

Using the count method really improves the performance of the code but I think it's still bad, so if you can give me some advice or clue it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

In your version, you indeed do not use `count`. Instead you do something worse. You still iterate the string (in `letter_occurrence`) *and* you also are building a hash (that's the extra work).

Ruby's `String#count` (that the other version is using) is [implemented in C](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-count). That, and the fact that it doesn't build a temp hash can explain the difference in performance.

Comment: But in my version I iterate the string just once, why is that worse than calling count for each character in the string? Why building a hash would be a problem? I mean, I've always thought that the key access is performed in constant time on average

Comment: Indeed, you do build that hash once per word. Well, must be the C version is _that_ more efficient.

Comment: If we assume that words have some reasonable upper bound on size in the real world (say no more than a thousand letters), then worst-case complexity of counting the characters of a word is also constant time. In the average case,  assuming English words, we are counting about 4.5 characters, which is quite fast, possibly fast enough that the time it takes to initialize a new Hash is relevant. You should benchmark and profile to confirm these hypotheses.

Comment: A lesson here is to not assume that constant time is always faster than linear time. It depends very much on the concrete characteristics of the particular algorithm and the data set it is operating on. There are many cases of algorithms with strictly worse complexity being faster in practice: for example, in many complex divide-and-conquer sorting algorithms (like timsort), insertion sort is used when the array being sorted becomes smaller than some bound, because it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

As your answer has been answered I will propose an alternative solution which I believe should be relatively efficient. The key is that I creat *counting hashes* for each word in `b` before iterating over the words in `a`.

```
a = ["dangled", "glad", "gladden", "dogged"] 
b = ["gad", "lag", "dad"]

ba = b.map { |w| w.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 } }
  #=> [{"g"=>1, "a"=>1, "d"=>1}, {"l"=>1, "a"=>1, "g"=>1}, {"d"=>2, "a"=>1}]
a.select do |w|
  ah = w.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  ba.all? { |wh| wh.all? { |c,cnt| ah.fetch(c,0) >= cnt } }
end
  #=> ["dangled", "gladden"]
```

When `w = "dogged"` in `a.select do |w|...`, we obtain the following for `ah`:

```
ah = w.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  #=> {"d"=>2, "o"=>1, "g"=>2, "e"=>1}
```

When `wh = {"g"=>1, "a"=>1, "d"=>1}`,

```
wh.all? { |c,cnt| ah.fetch(c,0) >= cnt }
```

first executes

```
c = "g"
cnt = 1 
ah.fetch("g", 0) >= 1 #=> 2 >= 1 => true
```

Since `"g"` passes the test we next calculate

```
c = "a"
cnt = 1 
ah.fetch("a", 0) >= 1 #=> 0 >= 1 => false
```

`ah.fetch("a", 0)` returns `0` because `ah` does not have a key `"a"`.

As `h.fetch("a", 0) >= 1` returns `false`, `wh.all? { ... }` returns `false`, so `w = "dogged"` is not selected.

Performance might be improved by reordering the hashes in `ba` (by decreasing word length, say) and/or reordering the key/value pair in each element of `ba` (by decreasing values or increasing frequency in English texts [`'z'` first, `'e'` last], say).